# Как задать в приложении свой шрифт?

Tags: android, android-studio, шрифты, textview

Как добавить в приложение свой шрифт и присвоить элементу TextView?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите ваше внимание: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20custom%20font&es_th=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Краткий вариант

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(<your TextView ID>);
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<file name>");
textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Но лучше (ну, просто кто-то любит более полные решения и не любит копировать одно и то же для всех 128 TexView в приложении) отнаследоваться от TextView:

com/example/foo/view/FontableTextView.java

```
public class FontableTextView extends TextView {
    public FontableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        UiUtil.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs,
                R.styleable.com_example_foo_view_FontableTextView,
                R.styleable.com_example_foo_view_FontableTextView_font);
    }

    public FontableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        UiUtil.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs,
                R.styleable.com_example_foo_view_FontableTextView,
                R.styleable.com_example_foo_view_FontableTextView_font);
    }
}
```

res/values/attr.xml

```
<resources>
    ...
    <attr name="font" format="string" />
    <declare-styleable name="com.example.foo.view.FontableTextView">
        <attr name="font" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

res/layuot/main_activity.xml

```
...
<com.example.foo.FontableTextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:font="coolfont.ttf" />
...
```

com/example/foo/utils/UiUtil.java

```
public class UiUtil {

    public static final String TAG = "UiUtil";

    public static void setCustomFont(View textViewOrButton, Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs, int[] attributeSet, int fontId) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attributeSet);
        String customFont = a.getString(fontId);
        setCustomFont(textViewOrButton, ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    private static boolean setCustomFont(View textView, Context ctx, String asset) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(asset))
            return false;
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = getFont(ctx, asset);
            if (textView instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) textView).setTypeface(tf);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + asset, e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static final Hashtable<String, SoftReference<Typeface>> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, SoftReference<Typeface>>();

    public static Typeface getFont(Context c, String name) {
        synchronized (fontCache) {
            if (fontCache.get(name) != null) {
                SoftReference<Typeface> ref = fontCache.get(name);
                if (ref.get() != null) {
                    return ref.get();
                }
            }

            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                    c.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/" + name
            );
            fontCache.put(name, new SoftReference<Typeface>(typeface));

            return typeface;
        }
    }

}
```

Сам шрифт положить в assets/fonts, в частности:

```
 assets/fonts/coolfont.ttf
```

Comment: `if (textView instanceof TextView) {` намекает на то, что данный подход можно расширить и для других виджетов...

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface.createFromAsset
textView.setTypeface(typeFace)
```

Comment: TextView программа, этим приложением легко создать любой текст

Comment: Разумеется, первым делом вы должны скачать шрифт или шрифты на свой компьютер. В сети вы можете найти огромное количество совершенно бесплатных шрифтов