# Android: кастомные шрифты в приложении

Tags: java, android, typeface

Возможно ли единожды указать шрифты, например в не-активити `static` методе, чтобы потом их использовать во всем приложении?

Или же каждый раз для каждой активити надо их прописывать заново?

В static ругается на `getAssets()`.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428673/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нашел решение**

Чтобы в статичном классе студия не ругалась на `getAssets()`, необходимо передать в этот метод `Context`, а именно (на моем примере, в классе `StaticMethods.java`):

```
public final class StaticMethods implements BaseColumns {
...

public static Typeface setTypeFace (Context context, String font) {
    // По умолчанию ставим HELVETICA NEUE LIGHT
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvetica_neue_cyr_light.otf");
    // Выбираем нужный
    if (font.equalsIgnoreCase("normal")) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvetica_neue_cyr_roman.otf");
    } else if (font.equalsIgnoreCase("light")) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvetica_neue_cyr_light.otf");
    } else if (font.equalsIgnoreCase("light_italic")) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvetica_neue_cyr_light_italic.otf");
    } else if (font.equalsIgnoreCase("thin")) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvetica_neue_cyr_thin.otf");
    } else if (font.equalsIgnoreCase("thim_italic")) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helvetica_neue_cyr_thin_italic.otf");
    }

    return typeface;
}
```

Теперь в любой активити можно засэтить шрифт, передав в метод в качестве контекста эту самую активити:

```
public class ActivityOrganizerMoneyDetail extends Activity {
...

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setTypeface(StaticMethods.setTypeFace(getActivity(), "light_italic"));
```

Ps. Не забудьте перед этими действиями скопировать шрифты в директорию `\app\src\main\assets`

Comment: Кроме того нужно следить и за валидностью самого контеста. Так например, если контекст активности, которым были проинициализированны ассеты перестал существовать(система выгрузила активность из памяти), то может вывалиться NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Cуществует прекрасная библиотека [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Она позволяет установить глобальные шрифты и использовать их даже из разметки. Например:

В классе `Application` инициализируем шрифты:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
}
```

В базовой активити внедряем шрифты в контекст:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

И спокойно используем прямо в разметке:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

Либо в стилях:

```
<style name="TextViewCustomFont">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</item>
</style>
```

И так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать для указания глобальных шрифтов класс Application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //манипуляции со шрифтами
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

}
```