# AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(I) перегружает MainTread

Tags: android, resources

**Не могу понять с чем связана данная проблема.**
Судя по результатам трейсинга выполнение `AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(I)` сильно перегружает Главный поток и вызывает лаги (картинка трейсинга ниже). Но я никак не могу понять, что это такое и откуда берется. Сам я такую функцию не вызываю. Код очень большой (ок. 20к строк) даже не знаю, что из него выложить :)

**Мои предположения, это может быть вызвано:**
 - на экране появляется много текста, написанного кастомным шрифтом (в частности - в листвью с логами), через `TypeFace.createFromAssets()` - единственное, где я использую `assets`
- те же логи (в адаптере) прогоняются по-словно через `SpannableString` (определенные слова выделяются определенными цветами)
- на экране оч. много разных `View` (больше 100)
- что-то еще, что я упускаю

*Скажите, что вообще может вызывать подобные действия (с AssetManager)?*

[image: Результаты трейсинга]

[image: Результаты трейсинга(увел)]

Comment: Вы, поди, шрифты грузите для каждого TextView? Кэшировать не пробовали?

Comment: вот чо-то чувствую где-то в этом месте засада)) да, так и делаю :-/ Попробовал бы, если бы умел. Пойду гуглить, спасибо :)

Comment: [Как-задать-в-приложении-свой-шрифт](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428673/)

Comment: отлично! спасибо еще раз :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, `AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(I)` перегружал UI-поток из-за того, что шрифт подгружался каждый раз в каждое новое `TextView` (с учетом "окна логов" - их всегда было в достатке).
Решение с кэшированием `Typeface` полностью решило проблему.