# Шрифт заголовка activity

Tags: android

Как изменить шрифт заголовка для activity в андроиде?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428673/Как-задать-в-приложении-свой-шрифт

Answer (score 2):

Да и даже не один способ.

Первый из них это для подключения своего кастомного шрифта, а делается это примерно так:

```
String custom_font = "fonts/custom_font.ttf";
    Typeface CF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), custom_font);

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sometextview)).setTypeface(CF);
```

Но если у вас множество элементов TextView, то придётся писать под каждый из них подключение шрифта, а это много лишнего кода.

Поэтому вниманию второе решение, а именно унаследоваться от TextView:

```
public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
private static final String TAG = "TextView";

public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}
public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}
private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
    String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
    setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
    a.recycle();
}
public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
    Typeface tf = null;
    try {
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    setTypeface(tf);
    return true;
}
```

Файл атрибутов:
attrs.xml (res/values)

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="TextViewPlus">
    <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Ну и собственно Ваш файл activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.example.TextViewPlus
    android:id="@+id/textViewPlus1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/showingOffTheNewTypeface"
    foo:customFont="saxmono.ttf">
</com.example.TextViewPlus>
```

Не забудьте файл шрифта saxmono.tt положить в папку assets.

Comment: А вы забыли кэшировать загруженные шрифты. И это фатально.

Comment: не вижу Вашей правки, смелей)

Comment: см. комментарий к вопросу. а ваш ответ приведет к http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497113