# Typeface font . В какой папке находятся normal, sans, serif. Суть методов позволяющих устанавливать шрифт в xml

Tags: java, android, typeface

К текстовому полю шрифт можно добавить в андроид студио через описание в xml и там я вижу есть три шрифта. Могу ли я в ту же папку, где эти шрифты добавить свой? Или это нативная папка андроид? Если нативная, то надо бы сделать так, чтобы можно было в xml указывать свой шрифт , а не каждый раз программно устанавливать или вообще объявить шрифт один раз глобальным для всего приложения, а не отдельного TextView. Что то подобное написано в ответе к этому вопросу [Как задать в приложении свой шрифт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428673) . Так вот поясните пожалуйста алгоритм действий написанного  в ответе кода. Типо : создается класс, который делает то-то , далее в xml делаем то-то.

И еще: вот есть шрифт qi.ttf ,можно ли этому же шрифту придать наклон пусть даже извращенным способ? или это уже должен быть другой подготовленный с наклоном шрифт?