# Как игнорировать шрифт пользователя?

Tags: шрифты, android

В своём приложении я установил свой шрифт, но на некоторых девайсах, где есть функция выбора кастомного шрифта (именно системного), мой шрифт не отображается. Есть ли возможность как-то это обойти?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать в приложении свой шрифт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428673)

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1315875/edit) ваш вопрос, добавьте подробностей, как именно вы устанавливаете шрифт в приложении?

Comment: покажите как вы его установили для начала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось элементарно: я забыл вынести установку на кастомный шрифт в файл с тёмной темой и тестировал приложение на ней